# Create modal datepicker dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have this code that works fine, but the window is not modal, so I can't get the date after it is changed. Please give me some advice or approach about it, thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
       new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

           public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                 int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

               TextView txtDate = null;
               txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

           }

           public void onDateSet1(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) { // TODO
               // Auto-generated
               // method stub

           }
       }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

dpd.show();

message("message", "Mensaje", mYear + "/" + mMonth + "/" + mDay, this, context);
```

Comment: What do you mean 'I can't get the date after it is changed'?

Comment: When the window presenting the date is opened, the program continue running, it doesnt stop until i get the new date. The dialog is not modal.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int storeYear = 0;
private int storeMonth = 0;
private int storeDay = 0;

private void  function openPicker(){
   final TextView txtDate  = findViewById(R.id.yourid);
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                   //TextView txtDate = null;
                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1)
                            + "-" + year);
                    storeYear = year;storeMonth = monthOfYear;storeDay = dayOfMonth;

    message("message", "Mensaje", mYear + "/" + mMonth + "/"
            + mDay, this, context);
                }

                public void onDateSet1(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) { // TODO
                                                            // Auto-generated
                                                            // method stub

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();

}
```

Comment: Same thing, the line 'message()'' presents the date after the function is called, the date picker window is behind, the message in front. I want the user to choose the date and then..the message.

Comment: Oh .this line is after the dialog show,not the data ischanged

Comment: First choose a date, then show the message. Like a modal dialog.

Comment: Why don't you move message into onDateSet?